# Deleting multiple keys in python-Redis in single command

Tags: python, redis

I have a list of keys, and would like to delete all of them. No pattern matching, nothing, just simple delete.
I don't want to run a loop, as there will be around 3-4k keys.

I was trying to pass a list into the delete function, but it didn't work

```
redis_keys = [key1,key2,key3,key4....keyn]
redis.delete(redis_keys)
```

In the [docs](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it shows

[image]

but not how to pass multiple keys. On SO too all questions are related to deleting while matching keys with pattern, but not with exact keys available.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `*names` syntax means that you can pass multiple variables via

```
redis.delete(*redis_keys)
```

which is really just a shorthand notation for

```
redis.delete(redis_keys[0], redis_keys[1], redis_keys[2], ..., redis_keys[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys you want to delete, you can combine your lookup with your delete via something like this:

```
my_key = 'items.per.day.*'
redis.delete(*redis.keys(my_key))
```